# neo4j increment count when adding relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, increment

The following Cypher query creates the `cnt` property and sets all to 0 when I run it the first time. The exact query run a second time updates the `cnt` property. Is it possible to increment node `cnt` for each relation that is added upon the load without running twice?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///graph_data.csv" AS row
MERGE (t1:Term {word:row.term1})
MERGE (t2:Term {word:row.term2})
WITH t1, t2, row
MERGE (t1)-[:TOGETHER {id:row.id}]-(t2)
ON MATCH SET
    t1.cnt = t1.cnt+1,
    t2.cnt = t2.cnt+1
ON CREATE SET
    t1.cnt=0,
    t2.cnt=0
RETURN t1,t2
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "increment node cnt for each relation that is added upon the Load"?

Comment: Its difficult to see why you would do this. Can you also explain your goal for this bit of code? It looks like you are trying to count how many nodes were imported?

Comment: @cybersam I am looking for a node "count" property for the total number of relationships. When the node is created the count would be initialized to zero. Each time a relationship is created, it would add +1 to the count. It sounds like the count can be determined via query and does not need to be stored as a property.

Comment: @F.Elliot I am looking for the relationship count. This particular value may not need to be stored as a property but I may want to increment values of other properties upon creation of nodes/relationships and I could not see how this could be done in the same step.

Answer (score 1):

The following query finds the counts (number of relationships) associated with each node. This seems to be a better method than storing the count as a property.
`MATCH (t:Term), (s:Term)
WHERE t <> s AND (t)-[:TOGETHER]-(s)
RETURN t.word, COUNT((t)-[:TOGETHER]-(s));`

Comment: If you haven't already - I strongly recommend buzzing through the [neo4j tutorials](https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-training/getting-started-graph-databases-using-neo4j/). You'll get a feel for what a graph database offers you if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be necessary for you to store and maintain `cnt` properties at all.

For instance, to find out how many `TOGETHER` relationships a specific `Term` has:

```
MATCH (t:Term {word: 'cat'})
RETURN COUNT((t)-[:TOGETHER]-()) AS cnt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I am looking for the counts of each node. This query returns cnt 1 for all nodes where it should be greater than 1 in some cases. I was able to find a query that gets the total counts.  ```MATCH (t:Term), (s:Term)  
WHERE t <> s AND (t)-[:TOGETHER]-(s)  
RETURN t.word, COUNT((t)-[:TOGETHER]-(s));```